# jQuery working with elements added dynamically with no refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built an web app working on the interface now I am facing a challenge of working with elements that are added to the canvas dynamically from jQuery.

Eg.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //On Focus for textarea of Sheet
    $("textarea").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("height", "250px");
    });

    $("textarea").focusout(function (){
        $(this).css("height", "");
    });

});
```

Now this part works fine and it expands and shrinks my `textarea` as required. (ALL GOOD THERE!)

However this is very my problems occur, I have `onclick` that `appends` new `textarea` elements to the canvas.

Now I can't use `.focus` on those or `.focusout` for that matter. When I use `.appendTo` page doesn't refresh. (New elements are added with out refresh)

How can I get around this problem (correct way), I need my `$("textarea").focus` to be able to work with newly added elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind them using delegates with [jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("body").on("focus","textarea",function(){
    $(this).css("height", "250px");
});

$("body").on("focusout","textarea",function (){
    $(this).css("height", "");
});
```

This will delegate the focus and focusout events to the matching selector ("textarea") when those events occur in the selector ("body"). If there is a closer element than body to select for the parent of this event delegation that is ideal, although not always possible depending on the dynamic nature of the page.

Comment: If possible, bind closer to the elements and not on document or body.

Comment: This works great, thanks.. ! I will accepted this answer when timer expires!